# Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit - Install screen prevents install

Tags: system-installation

I created a DVD install and a USB boot.  Bothe only get as far as the what Language screen and I am unable to choose or move beyond the strange screen.

Apprently being new prevents use of images. I hope the links provided work.

I am using an HP dv6707 laptop with 2GB memory.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Darent, thanks for making my links visible.

I got up this morning and seeing no answers, created a dvd for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - 32bit.  The install went perfectly and I am now exploring the Ubuntu Desktop.

Thanks again.